# call selenium-side-runner in jenkins

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-ide

I need to call the command "selenium-side-runner" in jenkins job it s not working even after the configuration in jenkins machin 
is there an other configuration needed in jenkins ?

Comment: please update your question. please put your error log of jenkins as well as what configuration you done.

Comment: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within the 300000ms timeout specified by jest.setTimeout.

       7 | jest.setTimeout(300000);
       8 | describe("suite2", () => {
    >  9 |   it("test2", async () => {
         |   ^
      10 |     await tests["test2"](driver, vars);
      11 |     expect(true).toBeTruthy();
      12 |   });

      at new Spec (../../../AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/selenium-side-runner/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine/Spec.js:116:22)
      at Suite.it (suite2.test.js:9:3)